# Cant seem to get CSS working on an appended table

Tags: php, jquery

I have an ajax request to a php file returning me rows of 3 values each.

I want to append these into a table. This works. I get my info in my table but I can't seem to add classes or id's and get some styling on it.

http://jsfiddle.net/AKh4n/1/

```
success : function(data) {
    $('#lijstbeh').empty();

    var data2 = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
    $('#lijstbeh').append('<table class="table">');
    $('#lijstbeh').append('<tr>');
    $('#lijstbeh').append('<th>Behandeling ID</th>');
    $('#lijstbeh').append('<th>Behandeling kort</th>');
    $('#lijstbeh').append('<th>Behandeling datum</th>');
    $('#lijstbeh').append('</tr>');

    $.each (data2,function (bb) {
        $('#lijstbeh').append('<tr class="tblbehandelingen">');
        $('#lijstbeh').append('<td>' + data2[bb].BEH_ID + '</td>');
        $('#lijstbeh').append('<td>' + data2[bb].BEH_behandelingkort + '</td>');
        $('#lijstbeh').append('<td>' + data2[bb].BEH_datum + '</td>');
        $('#lijstbeh').append('</tr>');
    });

    $('#lijstbeh').append('</table>');

}
```

**EDIT**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.tblbehpatienten').click(function () {
        var value1 = $(this).find('td:first').text();
        var value2 = $(this).find('td:first').next().text();

        $("#beh_voornaampat").text(value1);
        $("#beh_familienaampat").text(value2);

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'home/getbehandelingen',
            datatype: "JSON",
            data: {
                PA_firstname: value1,
                PA_lastname: value2
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $('#lijstbeh').empty();

                var data2 = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

                var table_string = '<table>' + '<tr><th>Behandeling ID</th>' +
                  '<th>Behandeling kort</th>' + '<th>Behandeling datum</th></tr>';

                $.each(data2, function (bb) {
                    table_string += '<tr class="tbl"><td>' + data2[bb].BEH_ID + '</td>' +
                      '<td>' + data2[bb].BEH_behandelingkort +'</td>' +
                      '<td>' + data2[bb].BEH_datum + '</td></tr>';
                });

                table_string += '</table>';
                $(table_string).appendTo('div#lijstbeh');

            };
        });

    });

});
```

It's doing my head in now. Can't seem to get it to work. Did i screw up a `}` somewhere?

**EDIT AGAIN**

`};` should have been `}` I have it working now. Thanks!

Comment: The class seems to get added just fine in your fiddle.

Comment: tr:hover { background: #FCF; }  something so simple isn't working...

Comment: elements are not appended like `xyz.append('<table>'); xyz.append(</table>)`  you have to include both opening and closing tag in the append function's argument like this `xyz.append('<table></table>')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to combine your appends into one single `append()` statement. Otherwise, jQuery closes tags for each one. Check out the DOM after appending. Your structure looks like this:

```
<div id="1">
  <table></table>
  <tr></tr>
  <th>Behandeling ID</th>
  <th>Behandeling kort</th>
  <th>Behandeling datum</th>
  <tr class="tbl" <="" tbody=""></tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
</div>
```

As you can see, that is not a valid table.

Also, in your `click` handler, you are referring to an element with ID "tbl", but it should be a class reference like `.tbl`.

I have also changed your `click` handler to be deferred using jQuery's [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events).

```
 $('#1').append('<table>'+
                '<tr><th>Behandeling ID</th>'+
                '<th>Behandeling kort</th>'+
                '<th>Behandeling datum</th></tr>'+
                '<tr class="tbl"><td>' + "1" + '</td>'+
                '<td>' + "2" + '</td>'+
                '<td>' + "3" + '</td></tr>'+
                '</table>');

$(document).on('click','tr.tbl',function(){
    alert("dfmlgk");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AKh4n/2/

### EDIT:

Alternately, you can use [`appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/).

In this example, I'm building the table as a string first. This might be more useful for dynamically generated tables. Building the table as a string can be done using `append()`, also; the example below demonstrates building the table as a string in addition to the `appendTo()` method.

```
var table_string='<table>'+
                '<tr><th>Behandeling ID</th>'+
                '<th>Behandeling kort</th>'+
                '<th>Behandeling datum</th></tr>';

for (var i=1;i<=5;i++) {
    table_string+='<tr class="tbl"><td>row '+i+' column 1</td>'+
                '<td>row '+i+' column 2</td>'+
                '<td>row '+i+' column 3</td></tr>';
}

table_string+="</table>";

$(table_string).appendTo('div#1');

$(document).on('click','tr.tbl',function(){
    alert("dfmlgk");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AKh4n/4/

Comment: How can i write this in 1 append statement whem I have a loop in there?

Comment: Please see my edited answer about building the table as a string before appending.